# Linux error - sort: both SI and IEC prefixes present on units

Tags: linux, sorting, hadoop-streaming

I'm using Python for Hadoop Streaming, and have a problem with sorting. My test data gives desired outcome:

```
cat movies.dat smallest.dat users.dat | ./Mapper.py | sort -h
```

displays output:

```
Boomerang (1992)::F::3
```

However, non-test data doesn't:

```
cat movies.dat ratings.dat users.dat | ./Mapper.py | sort -h
```

Gives an error:

```
sort: both SI and IEC prefixes present on units
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

And as a result, the output from Hadoop Streaming is an empty file.

The test data was taken from the original file; *ratings.dat* from the MovieLens dataset, e.g.:

```
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
```

etc.

Can anyone explain what is going on, and what I can do?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the output of `Mapper.py` is supposed to look like?

Comment: Mapper output is supposed to look like `Boomerang (1992)::F::3`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the output order to `F::Boomerang (1992)::3` and the error went away. I don't understand why; but it's no longer a problem.